# How to set a value of @Html.RadioButtonFor with the user input from @Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: c#, javascript, razor

I have a razor @Html.RadioButtonFor, which takes its value from @Html.TextBoxFor value:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Sms, document.getElementById('@(Model.Phone)').value, new { Id = Model.Sms })
```

The problem is that

```
document.getElementById('@(Model.Phone)').value
```

is a JavaScript code, incorect in this context, but I have no idea how to rewrite the same code so it is correct.

Comment: Is the Textbox dynamically created? If it's not, you could fix its Id.

Comment: Nevermind, now I see what the problem is. I'm trying to figure a solution, brb.

Comment: yes, the TextBox is dynamically created

Comment: I'm doing the other way: setting the radio value from the textbox `onChange`. Is that ok?

Comment: that should work too, i was even trying that approach, but had a hard time with it as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paul, I had to make it the other way: from the textbox `onChange`, set the radio value.

Check this out:

```
@model string
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ViewA</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function changeRadioValue(newValue) {
                var radio = document.getElementById('idRadio');
                if (radio != null) {
                    radio.value = newValue;
                }
                else {
                    //do nothing?
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("theTextBox", Model, new { id = Model, onChange = "changeRadioValue(this.value)" })
            @Html.RadioButton("radio", "Default radio value", new { id = "idRadio", onClick="alert(this.value)" })
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The radio `onClick` is only for debugging.

Hope this helps

Regards

Comment: Big thanks, that helped a lot, though it turn out that my problem was somewhere else...

Comment: @Paul'PaweL'B You are most welcome. Is it a new problem or is somewhat related to this question?

Comment: @Paul'PaweL'B Follow up: please, don't forget to rate the answer and mark it as correct, or give any feedback so I can improve it. Regards